# Resetting state when bound to a Select component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My state looks like this:

```
this.state = {
  shoe: {
    selectedBrand: "",
    selectedEU: "",
    selectedUS: "",
    selectedUK: "",
    selectedFraction: "",
    thumbnail: null
  }
};
```

This is bound to several Select components like this:

```
<Select value={this.state.shoe.selectedUK.value}
        onChange={this.updateSelectedValues.bind(this, "selectedUK")}
        options={uk}
/>
```

After the user click a button, I want to reset the state, but so far I'm not able to do so..

This is what I've tried:

- Created an InitialState, but since the original state is mutated, I guess this initial state is mutated as well or is this a new instance?
- Tried updating the fields manually by using `this.SetState({...})`

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you make use of setstate to update state the state isn't mutated but a new instance is created and hence using an initialState object to reset state would be the ideal solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work by doing `this.setState({...})`, where `...` the object you want to reset to.

However, it is probably easier if you define an object, and then re-use it to reset everything.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.initialState = {
    shoe: {
      selectedBrand: "",
      selectedEU: "",
      selectedUS: "",
      selectedUK: "",
      selectedFraction: "",
      thumbnail: null
    }
  };
  this.state = {shoe: {...this.initialState}};
}
```

then you can reset with something like:

```
onReset() {
  this.setState(this.initialState);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, Chris. After resetting the state, I logged the state and it shows the same as what I selected in the different Select components.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Your object has more "depth" than I thought. Try my updated answer.

Comment: The issue wasnt with the state actually. Your original answer was correct. The real issue was the update of the Select component which contained an object and not a string.. I'll accept you answer.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen  Glad you figured it out. Though my update does make a true copy, whereas my original answer didn't